# How to pass onChange to a stateless component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been playing around with reactjs, and building some basic forms all works good but then it became complicated when i tried to break into smaller compoments
i have a simple component that has a form in it called XMLParser, and it has 2 smaller components inside called XMLInput and XMLResult.

XMLResult is pretty straight forward it just passes the value to as the props, but couldnt figure out what is the best approact to use XMLInput i couldnt get the binding to work with the child component, thanks for any pointers.

```
function EppResult(props) {
    const resultXML = props.xmlData;
 return <div style={styles.child}>
        <textarea style={styles.outputBox} name="resultXML" value={resultXML} readOnly/>
    </div>;

}

class EppInput extends Component{

  render(){
  return <textarea
    style={styles.inputBox}
    placeholder="Enter XML here!"
    name="xmlData"
    value={this.props.value}
    onChange={this.props.handleInputChange}
  />;
}
}


    class XMLParser extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);

        this.state = {xmlData : ""};
        this.state = {resultXML : ""};
            this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
            this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        }

handleSubmit(event) {
    console.log("do submit");
}

        handleInputChange(event) {
            const target = event.target;
            const value = target.type === "checkbox" ? target.checked : target.value;
            const name = target.name;
            this.setState({
                [name]: value
            });
        }

render() {
        return (
            <div style={styles.container}>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <div style={styles.container}>
                        <div style={styles.child}>
                        <XMLInput value={this.state.xmlData} onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                        </div>
                        <div style={styles.child}>
                            <div style={styles.formContainer}>

                                <button style={styles.formElement}>Run!</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
            <XMLResult xmlData={this.state.resultXML}/>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you have your own handler to handle inputs if the component does not have internal state?

Comment: what would be a better approach ? I want a dumbed down input element basically, lets says i will put validation on this input later on i dont want the parser component grow too big, so i create its own component. not sure its a good way of doing this. @AndrewLi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm seeing a number of problems:

- `EppInput` is the sub-component name, but `XMLInput` is used in the main component
- You pass an    `onChange` prop, but refer to it as
  `this.props.handleInputChange` --    it should be
  `this.props.onChange`
- Just a note--I don't know where the styles object is, but I'm going
  to assume it's available to all the components

I haven't tested this, but here's a basic cleanup, with some alterations to see some other ways of doing things:

```
// stateless functional component 
const XMLResult = ({ xmlData }) => (
  <div style={styles.child}>
    <textarea
      style={styles.outputBox}
      name="resultXML"
      value={xmlData}
      readOnly
    />
  </div>
);

// stateless functional component
// props are passed directly to the child element using the spread operator 
const XMLInput = (props) => (
  <textarea
    {...props}
    style={styles.inputBox}
    placeholder="Enter XML here!"
    name="xmlData"
  />
);

class XMLParser extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { xmlData: "", resultXML: "" };
    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    console.log("do submit");
  }

  handleInputChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.type === "checkbox" ? target.checked : target.value;
    const name = target.name;
    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={styles.container}>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <div style={styles.container}>
            <div style={styles.child}>
              <XMLInput
                value={this.state.xmlData}
                onChange={this.handleInputChange}
              />
            </div>
            <div style={styles.child}>
              <div style={styles.formContainer}>
                <button style={styles.formElement}>Run!</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <XMLResult xmlData={this.state.resultXML} />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```